# Python program to generate Google search url

Tags: python, python-requests

Having learnt about **request** module I tried to implement it.

**Code 1:**

```
import requests
search = str(input())
d={'q': search}
results = requests.get('https://google.com/search', params=d)
print(results.url)
```

**Output 1:**

```
Python

https://www.google.com/search?q=Python
```

Everything worked fine I copied the link and it gave the correct results but on improvising the code I get an **error** (the link output is not generated)

**Code 2:**

```
import requests

search = str(input('Enter what you want to search:'))
user_input = input('Enter websearch, images, shopping, news, videos:')

if user_input == 1:
    d={'q': search}
    results = requests.get('https://google.com/search', params=d)
    print(results.url)

elif user_input == 2:
    d={'q': search, 'tbm':'isch'}
    results = requests.get('https://google.com/search', params=d)
    print(results.url)

elif user_input == 3:
    d={'q': search, 'tbm':'shop'}
    results = requests.get('https://google.com/search', params=d)
    print(results.url)

elif user_input == 4:
    d={'q': search, 'tbm':'nws'}
    results = requests.get('https://google.com/search', params=d)
    print(results.url)

elif user_input == 5:
    d={'q': search, 'tbm':'vid'}
    results = requests.get('https://google.com/search', params=d)
    print(results.url)
```

**Output 2:**

```
Enter what you want to search:Python
Enter websearch, images, shopping, news, videos:1
```

That's the output I am getting without the link. I am new to Python programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` returns a string, so when you check `user_input == 1`, you're really doing `"1" == 1` which Python considers `False`. You should try converting the input into an integer with `int()`.

```
user_input = int(input('Enter websearch, images, shopping, news, videos:'))
```

Note that this will raise a `ValueError` if what is passed into `int()` can't be converted into an integer.